# Not getting retrofit log

Tags: android, retrofit2, interceptor

I want to see the logs of Retrofit request body
I implemented below code,with below code I am unable o get logs

```
 public static Retrofit getClient(String baseUrl) {
        Level logLevel = Level.BODY;
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.level(logLevel);
        new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(interceptor)
                .build();
        if (retrofit==null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
```

please help me in this case, Even I allowed logging in developer options,Still is not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably a mistake . You have not set the `OkHttpClient` to `Retrofit.Builder` this is why its using the default client. Change your code a follows:-

```
public static Retrofit getClient(String baseUrl) {
    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.level(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    if (retrofit==null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .client(new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                        .addInterceptor(interceptor)
                        .build())
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  // only instantiate it but not use.
  new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .addInterceptor(interceptor)
                    .build();
```

You could do as following:

```
OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
httpClient.addInterceptor(new HttpLoggingInterceptor());
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()  
                  .....
                  .client(httpClient.build())
                  .build();
```